# set up Xerces on ubuntu 12.04 to use with cmake and clang

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-12.04, clang, xerces-c

I want to use Xerces in my project, which I compile with the help of cmake and clang.

What I did is:

- download source
- extract it to a folder called 'xerces-c-3.1.1'
- cd into that folder
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `make install`

Then I wrote `LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib)` into my CMakeLists.txt, and `#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>` into my main.cpp.

It compiles fine, but linking doesn't work.
I get the following results:

```
Linking CXX executable DG5_RE
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `xercesc_3_1::XMLAttDefList::~XMLAttDefList()':
/home/reissmann/Dokumente/DGFromRepo/Source_Cpp_RE/main.cpp:(.text._ZN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListD0Ev[_ZN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListD0Ev]+0x1e): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMemory::operator delete(void*)'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::~DTDEntityDecl()':
/home/reissmann/Dokumente/DGFromRepo/Source_Cpp_RE/main.cpp:(.text._ZN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclD0Ev[_ZN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclD0Ev]+0x1e): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMemory::operator delete(void*)'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::~DTDEntityDecl()':
/home/reissmann/Dokumente/DGFromRepo/Source_Cpp_RE/main.cpp:(.text._ZN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclD2Ev[_ZN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclD2Ev]+0x11): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLEntityDecl::~XMLEntityDecl()'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE]+0x20): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLAttDefList::isSerializable() const'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE]+0x28): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLAttDefList::serialize(xercesc_3_1::XSerializeEngine&)'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113XMLAttDefListE]+0x30): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLAttDefList::getProtoType() const'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE]+0x20): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::isSerializable() const'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE]+0x28): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::serialize(xercesc_3_1::XSerializeEngine&)'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE[_ZTVN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE]+0x30): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::DTDEntityDecl::getProtoType() const'
CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE[_ZTIN11xercesc_3_113DTDEntityDeclE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_1::XMLEntityDecl'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [DG5_RE] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DG5_RE.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

What went wrong, and what is the appropriate solution?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to replace your use of [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/link_directories.html) with [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/find_library.html) and [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_link_libraries.html).

`link_directories` only provides paths which the linker can search for dependencies - it doesn't actually specify what those dependencies are.  Furthermore, from the docs:

> Note that this command is rarely necessary. Library locations returned by `find_package()` and `find_library()` are absolute paths. Pass these absolute library file paths directly to the `target_link_libraries()` command. CMake will ensure the linker finds them.

I'm not familiar with Xerces, but assuming it has only 1 library called "libxerces-c.a", you should probably have something like:

```
find_library(XercesLibrary NAMES xerces-c PATHS /usr/local/lib)
if(NOT XercesLibrary)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find the Xerces library.")
endif()
...
target_link_libraries(MyExe ${XercesLibrary})
```

You may need to significantly extend this `find_library` process; more `PATHS` than just `/usr/local/lib` could be given; you may need to find more than 1 library (e.g. a Debug version on Windows?), etc.  If the library has different names on different operating systems, you may need to provide more `NAME` options (remember CMake may adjust the search name - see [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES.html) and [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html)).

Also, a more helpful error message can be invaluable if the find attempt fails.  You could suggest to set a variable (e.g. `XERCES_LIB_DIR`) indicating the location of the Xerces library, and this could be added to the list of `PATHS` in the `find_library` call.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. But unfortunately I didn't get it to work. I added these lines in my CMakeLists.txt: `find_library( PATH_TO_XERCES libxerces-c /usr/local/lib/ )
    IF(NOT PATH_TO_XERCES)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find the Xerces library.")
    ENDIF()
target_link_libraries (DG5_RE ${PATH_TO_XERCES})` and I get the error "Failed to find the Xerces library". But I did in shell: `locate xerces` and the output is: `/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.so
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.la
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so
` So it should work...

Comment: I think CMake automatically prepends "lib" to the name on Unix.  Can you try with the name set to "xerces-c"?

Comment: thank you! That was it. I will try to keep it in mind, that CMake prepends "lib"... Thanks again! Edit: can you edit your answer, that it includes that CMake prepends "lib", so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [FindXercesC](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/FindXercesC.html) is an easy and quick solution.

```
include(FindXercesC)
find_package(XercesC REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR} )

target_link_libraries ( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${XercesC_LIBRARY} )
```